# Change output directory for apt-maven-plugin

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

I am using apt-maven-plugin to process some Beehive Netui annotations before building a war.

The output of the apt processing is a _pageflow directory which contains struts config files (xml text) and the like.  The problem is that it is being output in whatever directory I run maven from, not in the ${project.build.directory}/classes directory which is what I want.  I tried setting the `outputDirectory` and the `resourceTargetPath` properties, but neither changed this behavior.

Is there another parameter to set that I'm missing?

Here's my current plugin configuration.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-alpha-3</version>
      <inherited>false</inherited>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
        <options>
          <option>web.content.root=${project.build.directory}/classes</option>
        </options>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>process</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>weblogic</groupId>
          <artifactId>beehive-netui-compiler</artifactId>
          <version>${weblogic-version}</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem really looks like [MOJO-1478](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MOJO-1478) (are you using a Mac)? Maybe have a look at the patch (and reopen the issue or create a new one).

PS: Don't you have to configure a factory? I don't get how the beehive-netui-compiler dependency is used here. Is the factory magically picked up from that dependency just because you specified it?

Comment: Yes, the factory is automagically picked up from the dependency.  I'm using cygwin on Win XP, but that does look a lot like the bug report.  Thanks.

Comment: And yes, that patch fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem with apt-maven-plugin
*outputDirectory* is ignored in mine maven project 
default value (plugin documentation) (${project.build.directory}/classes) is ignored too. source are generated in root of my project instead of the requested outputDirectory...

for your PS :

if factory is not specified in plugin configuration, it use standard sun feature, create following text file in your src/main/resources folder :

*META-INF/services/com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessorFactory*

this file have to contain the full class name of the factory, apt command use it

regards