# how to use the option configure in maven apt plugin?

Tags: java, maven

how to use the option configure in [maven apt plugin](http://mojohaus.org/apt-maven-plugin/process-mojo.html#options)?

can I set key-value in options or it only mean allowed option string?

Comment: seems you asked the same question already. That is not the way things work here, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

based on another stackoverflow question I've found: [Change output directory for apt-maven-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023569/change-output-directory-for-apt-maven-plugin)

I'd try something like this:

```
<configuration>
  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
  <options>
    <option>web.content.root=${project.build.directory}/classes</option>
  </options>
</configuration>
```

where `<option>web.content.root=${project.build.directory}/classes</option>` seems like the correct way of defining properties

**UPDATE:**
well others seem to use it as well:
see: http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/org/jboss/jboss-dmr/1.1.1.Final-redhat-2/jboss-dmr-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.pom 
however they refer in the parent pom: http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/org/jboss/jboss-parent/9-redhat-1/jboss-parent-9-redhat-1.pom
to probably custom patched version: `<version.apt.plugin>1.0-alpha-4-redhat-1</version.apt.plugin>`

also, I've seen it at: https://eclipse.googlesource.com/hudson/org.eclipse.hudson.core/+/3.0.0-M2-1/hudson-core/pom.xml however didn't figure out the version.

So I'd make sure you use the latest version of the plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-alpha-5</version>
</plugin>
```

or maybe the one before:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-alpha-4</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I tried:<option>key=19</option>, thus I print options in apt processor, it print -Akey=19=null,  what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
public AnnotationProcessor getProcessorFor(Set<AnnotationTypeDeclaration> decls, AnnotationProcessorEnvironment env) {
26        String page = null;
27        File output = new File("extension-points.wiki");
28        for( String k : env.getOptions().keySet() ) {
29            if(k.startsWith("-Apage="))
30                page = k.substring("-Apage=".length());
31            if(k.startsWith("-Atarget="))
32                output = new File(k.substring("-Atarget=".length()));
33        }
34        return new ExtensionPointLister(env,page, output);
35    }
36}

<configuration>                     <force>true</force>                     <!-- disable staleness check -->                     <factory>org.jvnet.hudson.tools.ExtensionPointListerFactory</factory>                     <options>                         <option>page=Extension points</option>                         <option>target=${project.basedir}/target/extension-points.wiki</option>                     </options>                 </configuration>
```